# Does an offer letter need to mention the terms of termination of employment?

Tags: contract-law, employment, terms-of-service, india

I received an offer letter from a startup in India, which mentions:

> Your assignment shall be based in CITY_NAME and your appointment will
>   take effect from the date of your joining, which shall be not later
>   than DATE_SPECIFIED. You will be on probation for a period of six
>   months from the date of your joining and you will be issued a detailed
>   letter of appointment at the time of joining duties.

Since it mentions a probation period of 6 months, is it necessary that they also mention the conditions under which the employer or employee could terminate the employment during the probation period?

Or, is the condition for termination to be mentioned only in the appointment letter which is issued at the time of joining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in the absence of specific terms regarding termination then the law of the relevant jurisdiction will be applicable including what "probation" means.